# Websphere MQ Queue Depth with XMS.Net

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

Since we are experiencing some trouble with IBM's Websphere MQ using XMS.net (Windows service that sometimes seems to give up listening for messages on a queue) we would like to create a simple application to monitor the depths of some queues (or number of messages on the queue) to be able to alert someone when the queue depth exceeds a certain threshold. This application would be launched by the task scheduler on a specific interval and would "read out" for X queues their queue depth (and maybe some other statistics).

Our windows service is using the following code and I was hoping I could reuse that same "knowledge" for our "monitoring" application.

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

    //Read config values
    string QueueManager = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queuemanager"];
    string Channel = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["channel"];
    string Queue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queue"];
    string HostIP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
    int Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);

    //Create connection
    var factoryfactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
    var connectionfactory = factoryfactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

    connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QueueManager);
    connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HostIP);
    connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, Port);
    connectionfactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, Channel);
    connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V2);
    connectionfactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);

    Console.WriteLine("Creating connection");
    var connection = connectionfactory.CreateConnection();
    connection.ExceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(OnXMSExceptionReceived);

    //Create a_session
    Console.WriteLine("Creating sessions");
    var session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge);

    //Create queue
    Console.WriteLine("Creating queue");
    var queue = session.CreateQueue(string.Format("queue://{0}/{1}", QueueManager, Queue));
```

I have browsed through the properties of `session`, `queue` etc. but, ofcourse, there are no "current queue depth" properties. I could use `GetIntProperty()` or `GetLongProperty()` on these objects but I don't know which constant to use for that (I have seen IBM.XMS.MQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH but that contains an `int` and `Get...Property()` expects a `string` as parameter).

Long story short: how would I go about retrieving a queues depth with the above code as a starting-point? Is it at all possible using XMS.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using XMS .NET queue depth can't be determined. Queue depth is specific to messaging providers and not JMS/XMS, so you will need to use MQ APIs to get the queue depth. You could use MQ .NET API to find the queue depth. MQQueue.CurrentDepth will give the number of message in the queue.

IMO it would be good to investigate why XMS .NET service stopped listening for messages than write another program to monitor queue depth.

Comment: I have found a "workaround" using a browser (`CreateBrowser()` method on session object) and using the `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext()` methods to increment a counter. This is, however, not very optimal. The reason why it stops listening is what is being investigated (it just sometimes does, unreproducably although we have a hunch). Meanwhile we're creating this simple application to try and 'monitor' our queue(s) and alert someone if a threshold is exceeded. I will have a look at the MQ.Net API to see if that works out for us...

Comment: @Shashi: there are two versions of `CreateQueue` and `CreateTopic`, one in `ISession` and other in `XMSFactoryFactory`.  So could you please tell us what is the difference between them? Why there are two versions if they're identical?

Comment: I don't see any difference. Both create same type of objects. Please note creation of a Queue or Topic object does not create queue or topic on queue manager. These classes hold information on queue/topic to which application will create a consumer or a producer. So a Session object is still needed to create a consumer or producer. Hope this helped.

Comment: @RobIII, I know this was a super long time ago but we are having the same issue, listener just stops pulling messages off the queue and they back up.  You said you had a "hunch" as to why?  Can you recall what it was and/or resolution?  Thx!

Comment: Sorry, can't remember. What we ended up doing was 'monitoring' the queue with another process and if it passed some threshold we restarted the listener. Ducttape solution but it worked. We've moved away from MQ since, thank god...

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve it using, [as Shashi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520014/215042), the MQ API. For this you need to reference amqmdnet.dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\amqmdnet.dll) and use the following (example) code. Please note that this is a simple example, no exception handling etc. is included.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using IBM.WMQ;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Connection properties
            var properties = new Hashtable();
            properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "SOME.CHANNEL.TCP");
            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "12.34.56.78");
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1416);

            var qmgr = new MQQueueManager("MYQMGR", properties);

            Console.WriteLine("Local  : {0}", GetQueueDepth(qmgr, "FOO.LOCALQ"));
            Console.WriteLine("Report : {0}", GetQueueDepth(qmgr, "FOO.REPORTQ"));
        }

        public static int GetQueueDepth(MQQueueManager queuemgr, string queue)
        {
            return queuemgr.AccessQueue(queue,
                MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + 
                MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + 
                MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE).CurrentDepth;
        }
    }
}
```

This performs way better than [my initial "workaround"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518476/websphere-mq-queue-depth-with-xms-net/11520701#comment15225130_11520014).